# Input state not binding onChange on first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onchange

I have declared a state called account_type. I have created an onChange event which changes the value of the state upon clicking the div.

```
<div
          className="price-plan"
          value="star"
          onClick={() => this.setPlan("star")}
        >
```

The issue is that the account_type state does not get updated the first time I click on the div. It only gets updated when I click on it twice. Is there a way to update the state just by clicking the div. Here's an excerpt from my code showing what I am trying to do

```
    let isRedirect = false;

    class PricePlan extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          account_type: "",
          renderRedirect: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      // Handle fields change
      handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
      };


      setPlan(plan) {
        this.setState({
          account_type: plan
        });
        console.log(this.state.account_type);
        // if (this.state.account_type !== undefined) {
        //   isRedirect = true;
        // }
      }

      render() {
        if (isRedirect) {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/sign-up",
                state: { step: 2, account_type: this.state.account_type }
              }}
            />
          );
        }

        return (
            <div
              className="price-plan"
              value="star"
              onClick={() => this.setPlan("star")}
            >
              <h3>{this.props.planName}</h3>
              <div className="mute price-row">Name</div>
              <p className="price">Price</p>
              <span className="billed-frequency">Cycle</span>
            </div>

        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: `setState` is *asynchronous*, so it won't be changed on the next line when you `console.log` it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jayce444 suggests, `setState` do not immedeately updates `state`. So `setPlan` should look like

```
setPlan(plan) {
    this.setState({
         account_type: plan
    });
    console.log(plan);  // Don't expect immediate state change in event handler
  }
```

But you can use `this.state.account_type` anywhere in `render()` function. And rendering will happen after `this.state.account_type` is updated on first click.